# Responsive CSS has different rem sizes on mobile

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm using the [Bulma](http://bulma.io) CSS Framework and I simply cannot get my site to be as responsive as their homepage.

The site is [live](http://ethmail.tech). My < html > has the same font-size, and my dom structure is identical to bulma's main page. Yet mine looks awful on mobile.

Here's a snippet of my HTML page:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="hero-body has-text-centered">
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          <h1 class="title">Tiny Text!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html class="route-index">

    <body class="layout-default" style="zoom: 1;">
      <section class="hero is-medium">
        <div class="hero-body has-text-centered">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Somehow big text?</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

Bulma's page:

[image: Bulma CSS Intro Page]

My page:

[image: My Intro page]

You can test this through developer tools on chrome setting the viewport to mobile on both sites' main pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try adding this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This tells the browser to fit the page to the mobile screen, otherwise it gives you a 'desktop site' which is wider

Comment: That did it! I didn't even have any idea meta tags existed that could offer that kind of functionality. Thanks so much.